# How to append text to data results while including the original data in SQL?

Tags: sql, oracle

I currently have this but the result I get under the screencapacity column is just "people". How can I retain the original data so it comes up as "X people"

```
Select branchid,screenid,'People' as screencapacity
from screen
where (screenid = 'S1' or SCREENID='S3')
AND(BRANCHID = 'B1' OR BRANCHID='B4')
```

Comment: Please edit your question and show sample data and desired results.

Comment: What is X in what you wrote? Do you really expect us to be able to guess without your help?

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing you want something like this:

```
Select branchid, screenid,
       (screencapacity || ' People') as screencapacity
from screen
where screenid in ('S1', 'S3') and
      branchid in ('B1', 'B4');
```

Notice that `in` is simpler than a string of equality comparisons.

Comment: Thanks. This was perfect.